# urls for django modelforms

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a form by following django tutorial on [modelfomrs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). This is the url I used:

```
(r'^frm/manage/$', 'frm.views.manage'),
```

But when I submit the data, I get 404 page with this error `The current URL, manage/, didn't match any of these`.

My template:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/manage/">
    {{ formset }}
<p><input type="submit" value="Write data" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic HTML.

Your form is posting to the url `/manage/`, not `/frm/manage/`

```
<form method="post" action="/manage/">
```

Change the line to be `action=""`, `action="."` (relative urls pointing to itself), explicitly point to your view `action="/frm/manage/"`, or remove the `action` line altogether to post to the same URL as the view serving the form.